# why ajax modelpopup hides behind silverlight object?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have silverlight plugin on my page and some functionality to show panel as popup with the help of Ajax `ModalPopup` extender,

But whenever show modal pop up it hides behind the silverlight plugin i.e. plugin is always on top?

any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting isWindowsless to true when creating the silverlight object. Pass this in as a parameter. Windowsless silverlight apps have a z-index of 1 so you can overlay them. I did hear there was a performance hit mind you.

Code:

1. **If you're using `<object>` tag directly** then add:

   `<param name="windowless" value="true" />`
2. **If you're using `asp:Silverlight` control** then add:

   `<asp:Silverlight ID="foo" Windowless="true" ... />`
3. **If you're using `Silverlight.js`** then add:
   `function createSilverlight()
   {
     Sys.Silverlight.createObject(
       "HelloWorld.xaml",
       parentElement,
       "myPlugin",                         // Unique plug-in ID value.
       {
           isWindowless:'true',
          // Determines whether to display plug-in in windowless mode.
       },
   }`